# How to send a variable value to an API in Flutter?

Tags: android, flutter

This is the code, as we can see in the URL, at last, I have used "uid", but it is not sending a value.
Here uid will have the userID when a user log in, uid is sent from Firebase.

```dart
Future<List<User>> _getUsers() async {
    var data = await http.get("https://api.myexamplewebsite.com/example/customer/get/example/app?id=uid");
    var jsonData = json.decode(data.body);
    print(jsonData);
    List<User> users = [];
    for (var u in jsonData) {
      User user = User(u["customer"]);
      users.add(user);
    }
    print(users.length);
    return users;
  }
```

Can anyone help me out with this, please??

Answer (score 1):

You can add new parameter in your function. Then replace the `uid` in the url by the parameter:

```dart
Future<List<User>> _getUsers(String uid) async {
    var data = await http.get("https://api.myexamplewebsite.com/example/customer/get/example/app?id=$uid");
    var jsonData = json.decode(data.body);
    print(jsonData);
    List<User> users = [];
    for (var u in jsonData) {
      User user = User(u["customer"]);
      users.add(user);
    }
    print(users.length);
    return users;
  }
```

Comment: You're welcome. If it is what you are looking for, don't forget to mark it as accepted answer